# Which Layout to use with Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Recently delve into fragments and from what I understand to create a fragment you need a java class and the fragments layout. This makes sense. However what I cant seem to wrap my head around is what "container", or layout do I use to store/insert the fragment? In android studio you can use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxeFO.png) to insert fragments, or you can use any other of the layouts. But which one is ideal to use?

Also I saw in a reddit post that I shouldn't be using fragments at all and that its preferred to instead use Frame layouts and play around with your views visibility for the desired effects. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're slightly over-complicating the concept of Fragments.

Fragments, like Activities, don't actually need a dedicated fragments layout xml file. If you choose to do so, you can create the entire layout through Java code, *not that I will understand why you'll choose to do so.*

So for Fragments, you don't need a Java class and a fragment's layout file. The only requirement is the Java class, and the layouts file is just the preferred approach to inflating a layout, similar to how it is for Activities.

As for your question about the container of the fragments, it's really a matter of your app's design.

You can add a Fragment to your Activity or other Fragments, through the `FragmentManager` in code or through the `<fragment>` tag in your layout.xml files.

Neither of those are the best way or the preferred way, since it really depends on what your app needs.

Using the `<fragment>` tag will cause that fragment to always be added whenever the layout is inflated. This is actually VERY bad if your Activity requires dynamically switching Fragments due to your use of things like ViewPagers, Tabs, Drawer Navigation, or etc. However, it's GREAT if there's no need to dynamically switch fragments and for that specific Activity or parent Fragment, this fragment is a fragment that's always loaded.

For example, let's say you designed a flexible AddNew Fragment that's used in a Dialog and an AddNewActivity. Due to reusing the same screen and code, you decide to make this part of your code a fragment so you can insert it inside a DialogFragment or into another Activity. But, for those DialogFragments and Activities, the **only** Fragment it'll have is the AddNewFragment, so it'll make sense to just insert that fragment into the Dialog layout and Activity layout through the `<fragment>` tag.

As for the option with Java code, the preferred approach is to use a `FrameLayout`. **But there's no need to play around with any View visibilities!**

The common approach is to just use:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

A FrameLayout is used because it's going to be the container of the Fragment. In other words, the Fragment will be stored inside of this layout.

So in Java code, you can simply use this code to replace the Fragment inside the container with your new one:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, AddNewFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

*Optionally, you can use `add()` instead of `replace()` if you want the fragment to be placed ontop of another fragment within the FrameLayout container.*

So yes, to give a decisive answer to your question, there's no ideal way to add a Fragment to an Activity or another Fragment. Each option has it's benefits and drawbacks, with some working better for certain situations and others working better for others.

In the end, it really depends on what your App needs. If you need your Fragments to be flexible, so you can switch Fragments, then this must be done through Java code, because fragments added through the `<fragment>` tag can't be removed at runtime. However, if you don't need your Fragment to be replaced and it's definitely always going to be showing the same Fragment, then using the `<fragment>` tag removes the need to write extra Java code to load the dedicated Fragment.

One thing I really do need to point out is... that reddit page you read about is wrong. The 'preferred' way to use Fragments **is not** to use FrameLayouts and play around with View visibilities. I actually have no idea why there's even a need to change View visibilities.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, this really helped! And regarding the view visibilities, I believe I was watching a youtube tutorial on how to switch a fragments place with another on button click.

Comment: Hmm, you should see if you can find back that tutorial. Because if you want to switch a Fragment with another Fragment, you simply use back that `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, AddNewFragment.newInstance()).commit();` code. By saying `replace()` and giving the same container, you're essentially switching out the old Fragment inside that container with a new one. This is commonly done if you're using a Drawer for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView to get a better performance than FrameLayout.

[Here](https://youtu.be/RS1IACnZLy4?t=545) more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Fragment` layout, but this isn't very flexible. If you're just showing one `Fragment`, it should work, but using a `FrameLayout` and inserting your `Fragment` into it works better as this allows you to change them on the fly.

You may see a `FrameLayout` with the id `R.id.container` or something similar, and what this is used for is the `Transaction`.

For example, if you want to insert `FragmentOne` into your layout, you can just do this and it'll put it into `R.id.container`.

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```